# flexible system to destroy each records in batch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## client_skipped_day_controller.rb

```
class ClientSkippedDaysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_client_on_exist, only: [:create]

  def index
    @client_skipped_days = ClientSkippedDay.order_by(params[:sort_by], params[:direction])

    if params[:date].present?
      @client_skipped_days = @client_skipped_days.where('skipped_at = ?', Date.parse(params[:date]))
    end

    render json: @client_skipped_days, status: :ok
  end

  def create
    @client_skipped_days = ClientSkippedDay.create!(client_skipped_days_params)

    render json: @client_skipped_days, status: :created
  end

  def destroy

  end

  private

  def client_skipped_days_params
    params.permit(client_skipped_days: %i[client_id skipped_at])[:client_skipped_days]
  end

  def check_client_on_exist
    client_skipped_days_params.each do |day|
      ClientSkippedDay.find_by(day)&.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

My code works if I try to delete only one record, like a :

```
Parameters: {"client_skipped_days"=>[{"client_id"=>533, "skipped_at"=>"2019-02-24"}], "client_skipped_day"=>{}}
```

But if I try to delete each hash in the array, it's didn't work :(

```
Parameters: {"client_skipped_days"=>[{"client_id"=>533, "skipped_at"=>"2019-02-24"}, {"client_id"=>512, "skipped_at"=>"2019-02-24"}], "client_skipped_day"=>{}}
```

Only one record will be deleted, but how to add the ability to delete all records? which coincide with the parameters that come from the controller?

And it must be a flexible system to remove if 1 hash in the array and immediately a collection of hashes in the array. Tell me how to do it.

Comment: Can you explain how what you posted doesn’t solve your problem? I’m having a hard time understanding what you’re trying to do and what your requirements are.

Comment: @Nate I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping over the `params` and finding each record one by one you could also consider using multiple [`#where`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) queries combining them together with the use of [`#or`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or) and loop over the resulting records.

```
def client_skipped_days_params
  params.permit(client_skipped_days: [:client_id, :skipped_at])
  #                                           removed `.values` ^
end

def check_client_on_exist
  destroyed_records, undestroyed_records =
    client_skipped_days_params
    .fetch(:client_skipped_days, []) # get the array or use an empty array as default
    .map(&ClientSkippedDay.method(:where)) # build individual queries
    .reduce(ClientSkippedDay.none, :or) # stitch the queries together using #or
    .partition(&:destroy) # call #destroy on each item in the collection, separating destroyed once from undestroyed once
end
```

In the above example the resulting destroyed records are present in the `destroyed_records` variable and the records that could not be destroyed are present in the `undestroyed_records` variable. If you don't care about the result you can leave this out. If you want to raise an exception if a record cannot be destroyed use [`#destroy!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy-21) instead (call upon each collection item).

Alternatively you can destroy all records by calling [`#destroy_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all) (called upon the collection), but it will simply return an array of records without differentiating the destroyed records from the undestroyed records. This method will still instantiate the records and destroy them one by one with the advantage that callbacks are still triggered.

The faster option is calling [`#delete_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete_all) (called upon the collection). This will destroy all records with one single query. **However records are not instantiated when destroyed, meaning that callbacks will not be triggered.**

```
def check_client_on_exist
  destroyed_record_count = 
    # ...
    .reduce(ClientSkippedDay.none, :or)
    .delete_all # delete all records with a single query (without instantiation)
end
```

**references:**

- [`ActionController::Parameters#fetch`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-fetch)
- [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-map)
- [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#none`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-none)
- [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)
- [`Enumerable#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition)

Comment: This is honestly a much better answer than mine.

Comment: 2 things. 1.) You’ve got a small typo. Partition’s argument is misspelled. 2.) I’m familiar with `.or`, but I can’t wrap my head around the map reduce. Can you explain it? Also, what’s up with the none? How does that work? Does that not leave `where 0=1` in the sql?

Comment: @Nate Thanks for pointing out the typo, I've updated the answer. I've also added an explanation of the `#map` `#reduce` combo [here](https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/996fc9b5393baaca13c3ccf0bf12d778).

Comment: Super insightful. So the output sql does have a `WHERE 0=1` in it though, right? It just ends up being irrelevant since there are other `OR`s with that actually do return records? And if there aren’t other ORs, then it returns nothing, instead of EVERYTHING.

Comment: Yep, you start with nothing and expand the query with additional `OR`s. However `WHERE 0=1` is not in the query. The `none` is just a starting point from which you build the query. If nothing is added it will not even hit the database and returns an empty collection instead (since you can predict the answer of `0=1`). If the query is chained it will simply use the first (`OR`) chain as starting point.

Comment: Example: `(user.admin? ? Post.all : (user.guest? ? Post.none : user.posts)).or(Post.where(visibility: 'public'))` results in no `WHERE` constraint for the admin, `WHERE user_id = 1 OR visibility = 'public'` for a regular user (with id 1) and `WHERE visibility = 'public'` for the guest user.

Comment: didn't work :( I'll update my code in the post, and can you update your answer?

Comment: @AlexPoznyak What didn't work? Do you get an error? What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over your array instead of just taking the first value out of it. I don’t understand the params that you have, so I’m assuming that you want to do your `find_by` using the Hash of `client_id` and `skipped_at`.

Also, Ruby 2.3.0 introduced the safe navigation operator, which is what that `&.` is if you aren’t used to it. http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/

Since `find_by` either returns an ActiveRecord object or nil, it’s a great time to use the safe navigation operator to shorten things up.

```
  def client_skipped_days_params
    params.permit(client_skipped_days: %i[client_id skipped_at])[:client_skipped_days]
  end

  def check_client_on_exist
    client_skipped_days_params.each do |day|
      ClientSkippedDay.find_by(day)&.destroy
    end
  end
```

Note, I’m not sure what your client_skipped_day Hash is. I assumed you’re making it possible to delete a single day, or delete in bulk. I would warn against having it do two things. Just make the client always send an array for this action and things will be easier for you. If you can do that, then you can make `client_skipped_days` required.

```
  def client_skipped_days_params
    params.require(:client_skipped_days).permit(%i[client_id skipped_at])
  end
```

This will raise a 422 error to the client if they don’t provide the client_skipped_days key.

If this isn’t possible, then you’ll need to add an `if` to `check_on_exist` to make sure that `client_skipped_days_params` is not null (because they’re using `client_skipped_day`).

Comment: almost work ...  NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: Thanks very much. All works fine, but i  modified a bit :)

Comment: Ahh. Great! Yeah, I edited my comment a few mins ago with some caveats that I wasn’t sure about, because of the two hashes you had in the params.

Comment: If this solved your problem, would you be able to “accept” my answer?

Comment: Oh. I now see a typo in that I eached over `client_skipped_days` instead of `client_skipped_days_params`. Sorry about that!

Comment: I just fixed that typo